# Choose specific email template with ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have a problem with choosing specific email template. I have the following mailer:

```
class NewsletterMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def confirmation_email(subscriber)
    @subscriber = subscriber

    mail(to: @subscriber.email,
         subject: t('.confirmation_subject'))
  end
end
```

And two emails templates that are stored in app/views/newsletter_mailer:

- confirmation_email.html.erb
- confirmation_email.en.html.erb

Is there any way to set in this mailer action to use this: "confirmation_email.en.html.erb"?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mail(to: @subscriber.email,
         template_name: 'confirmation_email.en.html.erb',
         subject: t('.confirmation_subject'))
```

You may read more at [**Mailer Views**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views)